# Drawing a filled cube in C++, crashes out, no useful error to trace

Tags: c++, drawing

OK, so I am following along with a set of tutorials by Chili. Our homework was to create the code for a filled cube. I did this. Then I trued to simplify it for a function. Now it compiles with no errors, but crashes when I try to run it. I have looked at this thing for a long time and can't figure out what is wrong. I will be comparing this to Chili's momentarily. But I was hoping for a fresh pair of eyes here. I think what's happening is another of those obscure and strange C++ laws that make no sense at all. But maybe there is a logic error here.

Please note I took the code from the function and turned it back into a normal C++ statement. Here it is:

```
int xN = 200;
int yN = 100;
int xP = 600;
int yP = 500;

while(xN <= xP)
{
    while(yN <= yP)
    {
        gfx.PutPixel(xN, yN, 100, 150, 255);
        xN++;
    }
    yN++;
}
```

I appreciate your help!

UPDATE!
OK, I fixed my code. Created two user variables (constant values) for xP and yP. Wasn't drawing a filled cube before. Turns out that scope or something is the issue. If I declare the two variables outside the loops nothing happens. Only when I declare each one just outside the loop where it is used does it work. So now I have to turn this back into a function somehow...

```
int xN = 200;
while(xN <= xP)
{
    int yN = 100;
    while(yN <= yP)
    {
        gfx.PutPixel(xN, yN, 100, 150, 255);
        yN++;
    }
    xN++;
}
```

OK, so if anyone else wants to know this is how I made my functions (turns out I needed two):

```
void Game::DrawCubeX(int xN, int yN)
{
while(xN <= xP)
{
    gfx.PutPixel(xN, yN, 100, 150, 255);
    xN++;
}
}

void Game::DrawCubeY(int xN, int yN)
{
while(yN <= yP)
{
    gfx.PutPixel(xN, yN, 100, 150, 255);
    DrawCubeX(xN, yN);
    yN++;
}
}
```

It won't work to nest the loops for some reason. If there is a better or more elegant way to do this with while loops please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i think it's in the inner while loop.the loop will never terminate because the condition `(yN<=yP)` is always happening to be `true`. the `yN++` should be in inner loop thus at the end of the loop the variable `yN++` increases `yN` and the loop terminates when `yN` is `> yP`.

Answer (score 0):

In inner while loop, it should be `yN ++;` in outer while loop, it should be `xN++`

Answer (score 0):

The `xN++`should be replaced with `yN++`. In other words, the code should be:

```
int xN = 200;
int yN = 100;
int xP = 600;
int yP = 500;

while(xN <= xP)
{
    while(yN <= yP)
    {
        gfx.PutPixel(xN, yN, 100, 150, 255);
        yN++;
    }
    xN++;
}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `y` every time through the loop:

```
int const xN = 200;
int const yN = 100;
int const xP = 600;
int const yP = 500;

for(int x = xN; x <= xP; ++x)
{
    for(int y = yN; y <= yP; ++y)
    {
        gfx.PutPixel(x, y, 100, 150, 255);
    }
}
```